# Mysql Query works only with Alias

Tags: mysql

I am wondering why this query works:

```
DELETE `temp` FROM `tagged` `temp`
INNER JOIN `tags`
ON
(`tags`.`id` = `temp`.`tag_id` AND `temp`.`user_id` = '1' AND `tags`.`name` = 'tag1')
OR
(`tags`.`id` = `temp`.`tag_id` AND `temp`.`user_id` = '1' AND `tags`.`name` = 'tag2');
```

And this query, the only difference being NOT having a `temp` as an alias for the `tagged` table.

```
DELETE FROM `tagged`
INNER JOIN `tags`
ON
(`tags`.`id` = `tagged`.`tag_id` AND `tagged`.`user_id` = '1' AND `tags`.`name` = 'tag1')
OR
(`tags`.`id` = `tagged`.`tag_id` AND `tagged`.`user_id` = '1' AND `tags`.`name` = 'tag2');
```

The second query just produces a syntax error. Additionally, please re-write the query that would work and doesn't need an alias.

Syntax Error:

> Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INNER JOIN `tags` ON (`tags`.`id` = `tagged`.`tag_id` AND `tagged`.`user_id` = '' at line 1 (SQL: DELETE FROM `tagged` INNER JOIN `tags` ON (`tags`.`id` = `tagged`.`tag_id` AND `tagged`.`user_id` = '2' AND `tags`.`name` = 'tag1') OR (`tags`.`id` = `tagged`.`tag_id` AND `tagged`.`user_id` = '2' AND `tags`.`name` = 'tag2');)

Comment: Can you add the syntax error to your question?

Comment: Is your error "SQL Error (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INNER JOIN `tags`" ?

Comment: See my answer below to fix that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to add the table name to delete from after the `DELETE` statement.

```
DELETE `tagged` FROM `tagged`
INNER JOIN `tags`
ON
(`tags`.`id` = `tagged`.`tag_id` AND `tagged`.`user_id` = '1' AND `tags`.`name` = 'tag1')
OR
(`tags`.`id` = `tagged`.`tag_id` AND `tagged`.`user_id` = '1' AND `tags`.`name` = 'tag2');
```